# Let L be a CFL. Is $\{1\} ^∗ ⊆ L$ a decidable problem? Is $\{1\}^∗ = L$ a decidable problem?

Tags: automata

I am working on some automata questions and I have encountered this problem:

Let L be a CFL.

Is $\{1\}^∗ ⊆ L$ a decidable problem?

Is $\{1\}^∗ = L$ a decidable problem?

I literally have no idea how to solve this, any ideas/hints? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please ask only one question per post.  Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

Here are some reasonably well-known properties:

1. The intersection of a regular grammar and a context-free grammar is context free.
2. The complement of a regular grammar is regular.
3. A context-free language over a one-letter alphabet ("a unary language") is regular.
4. It is decidable whether the language of a context-free grammar is empty.
5. It is decidable (in polynomial time) whether a particular sentence is in the language of a context-free grammar.

From (1), (2) and (4), it's easy to test whether $L(C) \subseteq L(R)$, given that $A \subseteq B$ iff $A \cap \overline{B} = \emptyset$. However, this cannot tell us whether $L(R) \subseteq L(C)$, since there is no guarantee that $\overline{C}$ is context-free. And in general, $L(R) \subseteq L(C)$ is not decidable. (In particular, there is no algorithm which could tell us whether $\Sigma^* \subseteq L(C)$).

But that's not the whole story. The subset relationship can be determined for certain regular languages. It's decidable if $L(R)$ is finite, for example, by simply checking each sentence in $L(R)$ for inclusion in $L(C)$, as per fact (5).

And, thanks to fact (3), it's decidable in the case that $R$ is unary. The intersection of $C$ with a unary regular language, such as ${1}^*$, is regular; the complement of a regular language is regular;  and set inclusion between regular languages is decidable.

Finally, note that $A\subseteq B \land B \subseteq A \equiv A = B$.